# vim `set nocompatible` not work in tmux

Tags: vim, tmux, vi

i install vim and tmux and config both of them, when i open vim directly everything is fine and works very well , but when i run tmux and inside tmux open vim , vim act like vi!.

i don't know what is the matter ? i even set `set nocompatible` at top of my vimrc file but it does n't any impact .
i repeat that vim it self work fine but when run into tmux then run like vi.

my vimrc configl file :
http://paste.ubuntu.com/24182927/

my tmux config file:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/24182928/

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the exact reason why your system is reacting this way but, as far as general errors with your config go, you are missing the following line in your `vimrc` file:

```
call vundle#end()
```

This line needs to be at the end of your `vimrc` config if you are going to use Vundle. For some context, check out the official [Vundle doc](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim/blob/master/doc/vundle.txt#L101).

I'm not sure what kind of issues this missing line may cause, but it is the first thing I would correct if I were you.

Comment: Thanks Dear Bryan but it did n't fix my issue

Comment: What is the actual user experience? You said you vim is "running like vi." What in particular are you noticing? Also, does vim appear to be able to locate your `vimrc` when you experience this problem (i.e. are any of your other `vimrc` configurations taking effect)?

Comment: Also, make sure that `filetype plugin indent on` is placed below `call vundle#end()`. Once again, not sure why this would cause an issue, but I don't pretend to understand the inner workings of Vundle either.

Comment: user experience ? when run vim inside tmux and use arrow keys like vi insert ^B , ^C , ... that means it does not run `set nocompatibel` but other configuration in my vimrc run without any issue , i think one of the plugin i used has `set compatible` in it  , i don't know maybe it is something else ..

Comment: i added `call vundle#end()` but  not any affect

Comment: Ahhh. Try adding `set -g default-terminal "xterm"` to your `.tmux.conf`. I've had this same issue. That's what fixed it I believe. I believe [this](https://superuser.com/questions/237751/messed-up-keys-in-vim-when-running-inside-tmux) question is what originally led to me finding a solution.

Comment: i change my default terminal it fix that problem but cause some new problem colorscheme not work well after that so i  change term in vim and tmux to xterm-256color and i still  has problem